# how do i get echo to type out a % in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want the code below to work or something that does the same thing.

```
@echo off
echo 100%
pause
```

When you open the .bat file it shuld look like this.

```
100%
Press any key to continue . . .
```

So i want the `echo` to read out the % and not to be a part of a code.

I want it to work the same as for example

```
@echo off
echo hi
pause
```

I have only tried `echo 100%` because i am a noob at coding so i dont know what else to try.

Comment: Your question has been asked and answered multiple times before. There's no reason why using the search facility at the top of the page, with `[batch-file]` and search terms like `echo`, `escape` and `percent` would not have gotten you your answer. You should also familiarize yourself with [this question, and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699), which should cover most things you'll struggle with, (including the solution for this question).

Comment: i did not find any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The percent sign has special meaning in (Windows) batch files, it is used to indicate a variable. For instance, `echo %username%` will print the contents of the `username` variable.

To echo a literal `%` sign, you need to double it, i.e. `echo 100%%`